Errors on cubic fits are relative to the order of magnitude of the y-data, not fit quality
I am writing some mass spec data reduction software (specifically, residual gas analysis mass spectrometry). I recently implemented a cubic fitting algorithm as an optional feature, however, some of the errors on the t=0 intercepts I'm seeing relate more to the order of magnitude of the data rather than the goodness of fit. Here are some examples:
Before digging into these examples, I suggest that you ignore the 4/3 Ratio and 5 amu data; the 4/3 Ratio is calculated from 3 amu and 4 amu data, and the 5 amu data are the baseline (no gaseous species at 5 amu) so we always use an average instead of applying a linear/curve fit.

The errors are:
2 amu: 3%
3 amu: 6%
4 amu: 218%
40 amu: 67%
Basic observations:

40 amu forms a very clear trend and should have the lowest error of any of these fits.
3 amu barely forms a clearer trend than 4 amu, if at all.

I would therefore expect the error on the 3 and 4 amu fits to be relatively similar, maybe a little higher for 4 amu, and the 40 amu error to be very low; what I'm seeing, however, is that, because 4 amu is down around 3e-14 A, and 40 amu is down around 6E-13 A, these signals end up with relatively higher errors than higher signals.
Because the 2 amu signal (pesky ol' hydrogen) is the strongest and clearest of all, it ends up with the lowest error.
Here's another example:

The errors on the intercepts are clearly more related to the order of magnitude of the y-data than the actual fit.
Here is the cubic fitting function:
def cubic(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * x**3 + b * x**2 + c * x + d

def cubic_curve_fit(x,y):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(cubic, x, y)
    
    fitted_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
    fitted_y = cubic(fitted_x, *popt)
    intercept = cubic(0, *popt)
    
    # calculate the standard error of the intercept
    residuals          = y - cubic(x, *popt)
    residual_variance  = np.sum(residuals ** 2) / (len(x) - 4)
    intercept_variance = residual_variance * np.sum(x ** 2) / len(x)
    intercept_stderror = np.sqrt(intercept_variance)
    
    return [fitted_x, fitted_y], intercept, intercept_stderror

And here are the sample data for the two examples shown:
Example 1:
He 19371    CB2502 10min    2022-06-29T08:50:40 
time_sec    2 amu   3 amu   4 amu   5 amu   40 amu
4.589   2.499294E-10    1.883895E-11    3.761834E-14    -1.506364E-14   5.055386E-13
10.589  2.506302E-10    1.885923E-11    3.718189E-14    -1.425650E-14   5.364334E-13
16.789  2.510879E-10    1.886623E-11    3.406583E-14    -1.196330E-14   5.470421E-13
22.789  2.516341E-10    1.879266E-11    3.178908E-14    -9.997409E-15   5.628271E-13
28.889  2.518049E-10    1.881801E-11    3.205416E-14    -1.030216E-14   5.570411E-13
34.989  2.515727E-10    1.880201E-11    3.486602E-14    -1.284306E-14   5.819271E-13
41.089  2.518113E-10    1.874990E-11    3.815993E-14    -1.486189E-14   5.917647E-13
47.189  2.520151E-10    1.876996E-11    3.482708E-14    -1.231443E-14   6.122757E-13
53.289  2.521316E-10    1.874753E-11    3.708621E-14    -1.313210E-14   6.292820E-13
59.289  2.525987E-10    1.880525E-11    3.839327E-14    -1.173513E-14   6.401169E-13
65.389  2.526217E-10    1.875623E-11    3.478337E-14    -1.153751E-14   6.546364E-13
71.489  2.528286E-10    1.880495E-11    3.933710E-14    -1.402713E-14   6.577292E-13

Example 2:
He 19375    DD-001-2Z 1.3A 10min H2 RE  2022-06-29T10:35:05
time_sec    2 amu   3 amu   4 amu   5 amu   40 amu
4.015   3.003075E-10    1.853406E-11    3.788137E-14    -1.749695E-14   1.906308E-12
10.115  3.010267E-10    1.848526E-11    3.689935E-14    -1.372115E-14   1.971391E-12
16.115  3.021516E-10    1.844551E-11    3.358801E-14    -1.238172E-14   2.026581E-12
22.215  3.023470E-10    1.846641E-11    3.610105E-14    -1.268847E-14   2.061073E-12
28.316  3.025176E-10    1.843082E-11    3.634866E-14    -1.412068E-14   2.077293E-12
34.416  3.027519E-10    1.844532E-11    3.731457E-14    -1.460673E-14   2.100824E-12
40.516  3.024903E-10    1.845211E-11    3.567267E-14    -1.227749E-14   2.094991E-12
46.516  3.024803E-10    1.841460E-11    3.278208E-14    -1.151416E-14   2.146332E-12
52.716  3.027830E-10    1.839153E-11    3.441428E-14    -1.070870E-14   2.141660E-12
58.716  3.026755E-10    1.840048E-11    3.166340E-14    -9.503108E-15   2.180426E-12
64.916  3.028296E-10    1.839986E-11    3.476046E-14    -1.003601E-14   2.182314E-12
70.916  3.032093E-10    1.833680E-11    3.852904E-14    -1.189308E-14   2.218354E-12

What is going on with my errors and why are they so much more strongly correlated to the order of magnitude of the y-data than the quality of the fit?
EDIT: When multiplying y by 1E12, I get the following results which are only slightly different:


EDIT2: Example 3 to even more clearly demonstrate what I'm talking about:

In this analysis, 2 amu clearly has the highest scatter and I expect it to have the highest error. Conversely, it has the second lowest error only after 4 amu, which, in this example, is in the same order of magnitude and has a tighter fit. The difference in error between the scattershot of the 2 amu plot and the relatively convincing 4 amu trend is a total of 2.6%. That's it. Conversely, 40 amu, which forms a trend roughly as tight as 4 amu, yields an error of 54.6%. Do those numbers make any sense at all?
EDIT3:
By switching to retrieving the intercept error as the square root of the last term in the diagonal from pcov, I've managed to reduce the errors to far more reasonable levels:
intercept_stderr = np.sqrt(pcov[-1,-1])

Errors are no longer in the hundreds of percent range for very low signals, however, the errors are still correlating more strongly with the order of magnitude than the quality of the cubic fit.
Here are the new errors for all three examples:
Example 1
2 amu: 0.096%
3 amu: 0.193%
4 amu: 7.044%
40 amu: 2.202%

Example 2:
2 amu: 0.070%
3 amu: 0.132%
4 amu: 7.227%
40 amu: 0.873%

Example 3:
2 amu: 0.222%
3 amu: 0.278%
4 amu: 0.119%
40 amu: 2.121%


I don't know if this is related to your specific problem, but unless you have a strong theoretical reason to fit a single cubic polynomial to all the data points then you might consider a more flexible approach, like regression splines. See this page for an introduction to the issues.

I also worry about the very low absolute magnitudes of the y values and whether you are running into machine-precision problems. What happens if you multiply all of the y values by 1.0E12 first?

I've added the results of multiplying y by 1e12 to the original post. I'll also look into regression splines.

Re "The errors on the intercepts are clearly more related to the order of magnitude of the y-data:" yes, they ought to be.  What is the problem with that?

You left out the last part of my sentence, "The errors on the intercepts are clearly more related to the order of magnitude of the y-data than the actual fit." The errors are absurdly high with respect to a linear model, and appear more closely correlated with the magnitude of y moreso than with the quality of the fit. To me, this appears very wrong. Maybe I am the one who's wrong, but errors should correlate with the quality of the fit and with the order of magnitude of the data. I expect higher errors on scattered data, but not hundreds of percent higher because it's 1e-2 lower.

Take dataset A [1, 0.14; 2, 0.18; 3, 0.31; 4, 0.47] and dataset B [1, 11; 2, 25; 3, 33; 4, 39]. Should the error on the intercept of A be hundreds of percent greater than B by virtue of the numbers being smaller? Or should the error on the intercept in fact be more tightly correlated with the scatter on the data and how well it fits the model?

I have added a third example to my original post which I hope will clarify what I feel is the problem with that @whuber

Just to be clear: by "actual fit" do you mean "linear model;" and by "linear model" do you mean an ordinary least squares fit (as opposed to a cubic polynomial)?  Please note that the "intercept" in these two models does not mean the same thing--they aren't at all comparable, because the explanatory variables in the cubic model are (extremely highly) correlated.

By "actual fit" I mean the quality of the cubic fit; how scattered are the data? how well does the model fit the data? Are there any significant outliers? I do not mean to refer to the linear model at all when I say "actual fit". Apologies if I'm not using the correct terminology here.

The main problem is that the measure of "error on the intercepts" used in the question is a percentage error, of the standard error relative to the intercept. That's a problem with a least-squares model, in which case the root-mean-square (RMS) residual error estimates the quality of the model fit. As the intercept moves closer to 0 at constant RMS error/model quality (for example, just due to subtracting a constant from all outcome values), that percentage ratio necessarily increases without limit. That goes a long way to explaining your observations.
There are a few more things that you should consider.
First, double-check the code for intercept_variance. I think it's missing a factor in the denominator, the sum of squared deviations of the x-axis values from their means. If I'm correct, you are overstating the magnitudes of the variances of all intercepts by that factor.
Second, there is no need to invoke a non-linear curve fit. Your cubic() function is linear in the parameters (the requirement for a linear model), so you can use standard linear least squares.
Third, if you want to use a fixed polynomial across all the data values, it can be safer to use a basis in orthogonal polynomials instead of the raw polynomials that you specified; in R, that's the default. The raw polynomials lead to large cross-correlations among the regression coefficients. A quick test in R on the 4 amu data of your Example 1 showed a smaller standard error of the intercept with the orthogonal polynomial basis. The data frame amuData contains the Example 1 data and abbreviates the time variable to t. Here's the R code with the default orthogonal polynomials (and the R default implicit intercept):
amu4model <- lm(amu4 ~ poly(t,3), data=amuData)

Finally, it's really risky to specify a single polynomial for all data unless there's a strong theoretical basis. If you want to model an arbitrary smooth curve, a regression spline is a much better choice, as explained here. A quick test in R showed that a 4-parameter cubic regression spline (with boundary knots at time values of 10 and 66 to enforce linearity outside those limits) gives a somewhat preferable fit to a 4-parameter polynomial model for the 4 amu data in Example 1. With the above data frame, here's example code:
library(splines) ## loaded from standard R distribution
spline4amu <- lm(amu4 ~ ns(t, df=3, Boundary.knots=c(10,66)), data = amuData)

The ns() function is for a natural cubic regression spline. The Boundary.knots argument sets the outer knots beyond which linearity is enforced; df=3 allows for default interior knots within those limits that provide for 3 degrees of freedom in the spline, plus the implicit intercept. I arbitrarily set the boundary knots to be between the outermost time points.

+1 -- remarkably good and thorough advice.

Thank you for your reply! I am hoping you can clarify the points under "Second" and "Third" as I think I understand what you mean, but I'm not sure. For example, when you say "there is no need to invoke a non-linear curve fit", do you mean in general (there's no need to fit these data to a cubic model), or when it comes to calculating the errors? I tried researching fixed vs orthogonal polynomials and got lost pretty quick. Any resources that are geared towards people who aren't professionals at this would be greatly appreciated :)

As for the spline, I am not sure how to enforce the boundary knots that you've mentioned, but I'll try. The basic spline just fit all the data exactly, which isn't ideal, and when I tried to smooth it out, it ended up looking similar to a cubic function. Clearly there's some room for refinement there.

Finally, there is no theoretical basis for fitting the data to a single polynomial. Actually, the ideal fit would be a double exponential, a + b exp(px) - c exp(qx), however, the implementation for that turned out to be exceptionally difficult. One user mentioned that they'd had success with a cubic fit in similar scenarios, so I figured I'd give it a try when I ran into the error problems I posted about.

@ohshitgorillas the Second point might represent my unfamiliarity with Python; I take curve_fit() to be a generic nonlinear least squares fit. Your 3rd-degree polynomial model doesn't require nonlinear least squares. The predictors can be nonlinear provided that the model in linear in the coefficients. Your polynomial model is linear in the coefficients, while the proposed double-exponential model wouldn't be. There are many types of splines. The natural (restricted) cubic spline is what I had in mind, you used a penalized spline.

@ohshitgorillas I'm also not a professional statistician. For the non-professional, R typically has more sensible defaults than Python does. With respect to orthogonal polynomials, all I know is that correlations among predictors can lead to problems in regression models, even numerical problems when you are pushing up against machine precision limits. Orthogonal polynomials, the default in the R poly() function, avoid the inherent correlations among raw polynomial terms.

Would you mind sharing the R code for your spline?

@ohshitgorillas added example code to answer
